# how to show 3 button in row only and one button in column only using loop in

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

i want to display 3 button in row and only one button in column  i have done it but only 3 button should be in a row . How to manage this in a proper way. I just want to show buttons dynamically in matrix form. What is the proper loop for this process. Please solve this.

//here is my code

```
//  DPSGalleryViewController.m
//  DPSApp
//
//  Created by EDUNEXT on 18/05/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Edunext. All rights reserved.
//

#import "DPSGalleryViewController.h"
#import "DPSAppParser.h"
#import "DPSAppService.h"
#import "SharedPreferenceUtil.h"
#import "DPSGallery1ViewController.h"
#import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"
@interface DPSGalleryViewController ()
{
    NSMutableArray *imagearray;
    UIImageView *groupimageView;
  //  NSMutableArray *array;
   // UIButton *buttons;
    NSString *filepath1;
    }


@end

@implementation DPSGalleryViewController
@synthesize sv;
-(IBAction)firstview:(id)sender
{


    UIButton *aButton = [[UIButton alloc]init];//[[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 60, 80, 60)];
    aButton.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [self.view addSubview:aButton];
    DPSGallery1ViewController *galleryViewController =[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"gallery1view"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:galleryViewController animated:YES];


}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    //set frame
    sv.frame =CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
    // set content size
    [sv setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 1000)];
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    NSInteger intTagNumber  = 0;
    NSInteger intLeftMargin = 10; // horizontal offset from the edge of the screen
    NSInteger intTopMargin  = 20; // vertical offset from the edge of the screen
    NSInteger intXSpacing   = 85; // number of pixels between the button origins (horizontally)
    NSInteger intYSpacing   = 79; // number of pixels between the button origins (vertically)
    NSInteger intXTile;
    NSInteger intYTile;
    int k =1;

       for (int y = 1; y <1+k; y++)
    {
        for (int x = y; x <=4-k; x++)
        {

            intXTile = (x * intXSpacing) + intLeftMargin;
            intYTile = (y * intYSpacing) + intTopMargin;

            // create a value button, text, or image
            buttons[x][y] = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(intXTile, intYTile, 58, 58)];
            [buttons[x][y] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"gallery_back.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     //      [buttons[x][y] addTarget:self action:@selector(actionPick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
           [buttons[x][y] setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0 green:0/255.0 blue:92/255.0 alpha:1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
         //  buttons[x][y].titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"TrebuchetMS-Bold" size:42];
            buttons[x][y].adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
            buttons[x][y].adjustsImageWhenDisabled = NO;
            buttons[x][y].tag = intTagNumber;
            [self.view addSubview:buttons[x][y]];

            intTagNumber++;
        }
       k++;

    }



}
- (IBAction)actionPick:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    NSLog(@"Button tag: %i",button.tag);
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    [self updateUI];
    [self addBottomView];
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

-(NSString *)getURL
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@studentprofileid=%@",ROOT_URL,ImageGallery_Data,[[[SharedPreferenceUtil getNSObject:STUDENT_DATA_JSON ]valueForKey:@"studentprofileid"] valueForKey:@"studentimagegallary"]];
}


-(void)updateUI
{
    [self addCutomTitleToNavigationController:@"Image Gallery"];
    [self addCustomBackButton];

    if (IS_IOS7)
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Gallery_navigation2.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    else
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Gallery_navigation.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];








  //  NSMutableArray *datainview =(NSMutableArray*) [SharedPreferenceUtil getNSObject:@"gallary_data"];
 //   NSString *groupname1=[datainview valueForKey:@"group_name"];
//    NSLog(@"The group is : %@",groupname1);
//    NSLog(@"The data in  View is : %@",datainview);
//    [march2015label setText:groupname1];



}




@end
```

And the screen shot is here//[image: this is not a correct form, i just want from the top of screen 3 button in a row only and one in column only]

Comment: The button will be look like this in a matrix

Answer (score 2):

Its better to use UITableView with n numbers row and create a loop of buttons for each cell and add it as contentview of cell (as Column). Please set tag of button as below way -

```
  - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 4;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;

    }


    for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex <4; columnIndex++)
    {
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [button addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(aMethod:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        button.tag = indexPath.row + columnIndex;
        [button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0,columnIndex * 40.0 + 10.0, 40.0, 40.0);
        [cell. contentView addSubview:button];

    }


    return cell;

}
```

**Update**

```
-(void)aMethod:(UIButton *)sender
    {

        int tagValue = sender.tag;

        int columnIndex = tagValue%4 ;
        int rowIndex = (tagValue - columnIndex)/4;

        NSLog(@"Button clicked Row %d Column %d",rowIndex,columnIndex);
    }
```

Comment: i want to make dynamically according to web service.

Comment: But we can use the loop in matrix form .

Comment: yes , you may change row and column number dynamically and call [tableview reloaddata];